# How to join two tables using sub queries?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

How to join two tables using sub queries in oracle sql server?
i tried it this way

```
select s.*,p.* from salary s 
cross join (select p.* from pension p where p.sal=21);
```

Comment: Why do you want a subquery at all - is this a simplified example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to name the subquery:

```
select s.*,p.* from salary s 
cross join (select * from pension where sal=21) p
```